# Primary Key follows me

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table where primary key are auto_increment id. I have a simple code to retrive worlds from table:

```
 Server.select('world')
```

But with world list i got empty primary key id for all worlds and output looks like:

```
[{"world":"Sandbox","id":null},{"world":"CogitoR4","id":null},{"world":"CarnageR4","id":null},{"world":"Theos","id":null},{"world":"AmberR4","id":null},{"world":"DedalR2","id":null},{"world":"HiTech152","id":null},{"world":"Davids152","id":null},{"world":"Magnus152","id":null}]
```

How i can fix this?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `servers` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `players` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `maximum` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `port` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '25565',
  `server_type` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `world` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `map` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `server` (`name`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip`)
)
```

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: @rlecaro2 Dont understand your question

Comment: Nvm since you answered the question. Be sure you didn't specify a relation between Server and World, since the latter is an attribute of the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `.pluck` method:

```
Server.pluck(:world)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck

Comment: Wow! Awesome! Love you :3

Comment: But if i wanna retrive single row?

Comment: Just add whatever conditions you need: `Server.pluck(:world).where(...conditions...)`

Comment: Server.pluck(:world).where(name: 'Sandbox').take
   (3.2ms)  SELECT `servers`.`world` FROM `servers`
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x00000002f9fd38>

Comment: Ah sorry. Put the `.pluck` component on the end ... `Server.where(name: 'Sandbox').pluck(:world)`

Answer (score 0):

First I create a sample model called `Server`

```
% rails g model server world:string foo:string bar:string
```

Migrate the database

```
% rake db:migrate
```

Startup console and create some sample data

```
% rails c
> Server.create world: "hello", foo: "a", bar: "a"
> Server.create world: "sample", foo: "b", bar: "b"
```

Select just the `world` field

```
> Server.select(:world)
# SELECT world FROM "servers"
# => [#<Server world: "hello">, #<Server world: "sample">]
```

Select `world` and `id` fields

```
> Server.select(:world).select(:id)
# SELECT id, world FROM "servers"
# => [#<Server id: 1, world: "hello">, #<Server id: 2, world: "sample">]
```

**Note:** the `foo` and `bar` fields have not been selected

---

It even works with a `.to_json` call

```
> Server.select(:world).to_json
# SELECT world FROM "servers"
# => "[{\"world\":\"hello\"},{\"world\":\"sample\"}]"
```

You can chain in other conditions to narrow your selection

```
> Server.where(foo: "a").select(:world)
# Server Load (0.2ms)  SELECT world FROM "servers" WHERE "servers"."foo" = 'a'
# => [#<Server world: "hello">]
```

Comment: I use already existed table. You provide basics and i understand that. But i dont understand why i get primary key with my query

Comment: Ok, well you have some records that don't have ids. That's not a problem that `.select` can solve for you. Fix your broken ids and then `Server.select(:id).select(:world)` will work fine for you.

Comment: I dont need id. I need only world rows.

Comment: I am not selecting it =.= Server.select(:world) get met also empty id.

Comment: Server.select(:world)
  Server Load (1.5ms)  SELECT world FROM `servers`
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Server id: nil, world: "Sandbox">, #<Server id: nil, world: "CogitoR4">, #<Server id: nil, world: "CarnageR4">, #<Server id: nil, world: "Theos">, #<Server id: nil, world: "AmberR4">, #<Server id: nil, world: "DedalR2">, #<Server id: nil, world: "HiTech152">, #<Server id: nil, world: "Davids152">, #<Server id: nil, world: "Magnus152">]>

Comment: Not on its own it doesn't. It looks like your result is in JSON. How are you creating the JSON?

Comment: Look up..the rails c same output.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include the console output for the SQL statements. It does not include `id` on its own. You might have something else happening. Your code paste is somewhat sparse but you can see that given my elementary example, it's working fine.